# How is standard input implemented?

Tags: haskell, operating-system

In any programming langauge what happens when we ask a user for an input?

Let's say in Haskell we have the following code.

```
name <- getLine
putStrLn ("Hey " ++ name)
```

How would the implementation of `getLine` look like?

Is is right to assume, that this somehow listens to keyboard interupts and when the enter key is pressed, the function stops execution? if so then how does it wait? Is there a while loop of sorts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whew. On modern computers, this is actually quite a complicated question to answer. That keypress goes through a lot of computation before it makes it to the program waiting on it!

Here's a slightly simplified version.

First, the program asks the operating system for a chunk of input. If there's been some input since the last time the program asked, the operating system returns that input immediately and your program proceeds on its merry way. If there hasn't, the operating system suspends the program and puts it on a special watch list. The operating system then switches over to other programs that need time on the processor, or, if there aren't currently any, puts the computer to sleep for a few nanoseconds. The computer continues operating as normal, processing other programs and sleeping when none are available, until the operating system detects keyboard input that should go to your program. When it does, it consults its watch list, wakes up your process, and returns control to your program with the input it received.

So that's one loop: the operating system loops over its lists of programs waiting for various things (including those just waiting for more compute time) until it receives keyboard input. And then there's a second loop inside your program, which keeps asking for more chunks of input until one of them contains a newline.

The reason it's important to know about both loops, rather than just saying "yeah your program has a loop in it that waits", is this: because of this architecture, your program does not need to implement the logic that suspends computation until a keyboard interrupt fires. The loop that waits for that interrupt is all implemented in the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

> How would the implementation of getLine look like?
>
> Is it right to assume, that this somehow listens to keyboard interupts and when the enter key is pressed, the function stops execution?

The programmers of most language's `getLine` function generally do not need to care about interrupts or even waiting. Haskell is a bit special, but in most languages, the pseudocode can basically just look like this:

```
loop:
  ask the OS for 1 character
  if reached EOF or Enter:
     return the string
  append character to the string
```

Asking the OS for a character comes in the form of calling an OS provided function (syscall) `read(myInputSource, myBufferSpace, maxBytesToRead)`. This function will not return until a character is available, so the `getLine` programmer doesn't even have to add waiting.

What a real OS has to go through to provide this `read()` function is fascinating and complex (and the basis of [a common interview question](https://github.com/alex/what-happens-when)). However, the person writing `getLine` only needs to trust that the OS does its job.

Comment: I don't think `read` is often called to request one character. Typically it'll ask to read enough to fill an input buffer. This will block if nothing is available to read, but will return one or more characters if there's something to read; it won't wait for the full request to be satisfied.

Comment: Yes, this is a very efficient optimization that most libraries use. It's not conceptually required though, and e.g. Unix shells will in fact read lines from a terminal a single byte at a time.

Comment: What do they gain from using single-character reads?

Comment: They have to share the same input stream with the programs they invoked, and there is no mechanism to share input buffers, only FDs. If the input is `python -i\nprint("Hi")\n` then the shell has to be careful to read only `python -i\n` and no more, so that `python` will find `print("Hi")\n` when it in turn tries to read.

Comment: Ah, I see. Too bad there's no operation to peek ahead in the file descriptor buffer without consuming it.